# Log all queries in last 60 mins in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose

I want to find all operations list done by the user on MongoDB collection in the last 60 mins. Queries like insertion, updation, and deletion of data.

For Insertion and Updation query :
I mention the timestamp field in the schema and run this

`db.collectionName.find({timestamp : {$gte: new Date().getTime()-(60*60*1000) } } )`

And, find all data which is updated or inserted in the last 60 mins. But still, deletion queries are unknown. What should I do to figure out all deletion queries performed in the last 60 mins.

Basically, I want to design a function that takes MongoDB URI from the user. And find out all queries which he did in the last 60 mins and run all those queries to update elastic cloud database and make it as same as his database.

Comment: check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Comment: @dododo I go through the doc. but still, I didn't figure out a proper way to find all log queries. It is very helpful, if you elaborate little a bit

Comment: @dododo is there a way to know to all queries which is done in last 60 mins in mongodb using mongoose. I tried getLog() method but ii don't know how to use it with mongoose

Comment: the doc says: `Applications can use change streams to subscribe to all data changes on a single collection, a database, or an entire deployment, and immediately react to them`, so you can subscribe on changes that happen on your collection. Idk mongoose, but I assume it should have a way to configure it like in any other language drivers